# give style based on php condition

Tags: css, styles

Anybody know why `<div style="<?php echo $i==1?'color:#FF0000':''; ?>; display:block"></div>` is error, but if write in this way `<div style="display:block;<?php echo $i==1?'color:#FF0000;':''; ?>"></div>` it can worked, no problem.

For other attribute such like this `<div id="<?php echo $abc; ?>"></div>`, worked has no problem too. Anybody could tell me why?

Sorry for my language.

Comment: Hey man, what's the error you're getting? That looks about right to me, though I would recommend by starting by trying without the shorthand. Start with a <?php if($i===1){echo "color:#FF000";} ?>

Comment: have you try with this <div style="<?php if($i===1){echo 'color:#FF000';} ?> display:block">dfd</div>
the value $i=1; but the text still in black, and in dreamweaver, this line code is show in blue color. It looks could not read this line properly.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution:

```
<?php if ($username !='admin') { ?> //php tag closes
<div style="color:blue;"> //html line
<?php } ?> //php starts to close condition
//change condition in first line to whatever you want
```